# Blank page while Setting video on PHP page

Tags: wordpress, jwplayer

I'm using wordpress, but I want to create video on Php ,, where people can click on `http://example.com/play.php` and That can auto play the video. I have tried many times, but could not succeed.

This code I am pasting below head

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/jwplayer/jwplayer.js'></script>
```

This is where the video comes in:

```
<div id='movieframe'></div>

<script type="text/javascript">    
  jwplayer('movieframe').setup({

   'flashplayer': '/jwplayer/player.swf',
   'width': '480',
   'height': '270',
   'file': '/images/intro2.flv'
   controlbar: "none",
   autostart: true
  });
</script>
```

I'm using JW player plugin for wordpress, I don't know where I'm wrong. Please correct me. Just blank page showing.

Thanks

Comment: Any error in Javascript console?

Comment: You have error reporting turned on in PHP?

Comment: Blank page says not much. Is the HTML outputted?